# formatting date for insertion into mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using jQueryUI datepicker and making sure that the date, mm/dd/yyyy is shown to the user so they understand what they entered is correct. My only problem is I don't understand how to then take that date and format it to go into mysql date field correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy if you know a little PHP.
Because PHP being a string manipulation language, it is a must to know some string manipulation basics.

You can use strpos() function to locate position of `/` symbol and then use substr() to get numbers and then use `.` concatenation operator to get date parts in order

You can use very handy `explode()` function, to get date parts into array and then combine them using some variable interpolation, like this:

```
$d          = explode("/",$date);
$date_mysql = "$d[2]-$d[0]-$d[1]";
```

When mastered your string manipulation skills, you can start with real powerful voodoo of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STR_TO_DATE function in mysql.

`$date` is the variable that came from Jquery via Ajax, holding the date that user picked up.

`Insert into tableName Values('bla',  'bla', STR_TO_DATE($date))`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your MM/DD/YYYY string to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM-DD, and then pretty much any database (including MySQL) will interpret your date properly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_date_format));
```